# How to extract bytes from a hex dump?

Tags: c, arrays

```
typedef struct MY_HDR
{
    TU8 VALUE:6;
    TU8 EXT1:1;
    TU8 EXT2:1;
}MyHdr;

typedef struct MY_DATA
{
    TU32 BIT1:1;
    TU32 BIT2:1;
    TU32 VAL:3;
    TU32 VAL1:4;
    TU32 VAL3:10;
    TU32 VAL4:1;
    TU32 VAL5:11;
    TU32 VAL6:1;
    TU16 VAL7;
}MyData;
```

I have a hex dump, which is of the type MY_HDR + MY_DATA, where MY_HDR is the 1st byte of the hex dump. Now I need to analyze the contents of MY_HDR, for that I just need to extract 1st byte and typecast it into the type of MY_HDR. Then I need to analyze the contents of MY_DATA, for that I just need to extract the next bytes and type cast it to the type MY_DATA. Could anyone help me know (the syntax) how to extract just the one byte and bytes 2 to n from the hex dump? I am comfortable with bit operations, but not sure how to get the bytes. Also I have a pointer:

```
VOID *myMsg
```

which points to the hex dump.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Was trying to typecast myMsg to MY_HDR and (myMsg+n - myMsg+1) to MY_DATA. Will it work? I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

If the first byte of `myMsg` is the data you want, then you don't need to "extract" it. Just typecast `myMsg` as a `MY_HDR` pointer:

```
MyHdr *hdrPtr = (MyHdr *) myMsg;
printf("My header value is %d\n", hdrPtr->VALUE);
```

The following data is a little harder, since it's an offset from the beginning, and you can't use pointer arithmetic on a `void*`. You have to use double typecasting for that to work, and then typecast to a type on which adding one will only offset by one byte:

```
MyData *dataPtr = (MyData *) ((int8_t *) myMsg + 1);
printf("My data bit 1 is %d\n", dataPtr->BIT1);
```

(See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for where to find the `int8_t` type.)

---

Remember that you can use array-indexing with pointers as well:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    printf("dataPtr[%lu].BIT1 = %d\n", i, dataPtr[i].BIT1);
```

Comment: And how do I typecast bytes 2 to n of myMsg to the type of MY_DATA? Any help?

Comment: Can I define int8_t as **typedef signed int int8_t**?

Comment: @user3440736 No you most certainly ***can not***. Then you would define `int8_t` as a 32-bit value. That means that the `+1` would add a *four bytes* offset. Read the linked reference, it says which header is needed for the type.